# Regex Expression generating extra output

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this-:

```
st = "url=these,url=are,url=test,url=questions"
```

Now from this string i need to generate value of all the `url`. Now the regexp am using is something like this-:

```
import re
re.findall(r'([^\(url=\)]+)',st)
```

Now my desired output is `['these,', 'are,', 'test,', 'questions']` but my regexp is giving 
`['these,', 'a', 'e,', 'test,', 'q', 'estions']` this as output.

So, what should be my modified regexp and why my regexp is not giving me the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've used square brackets `[]` which select characters. You've got `[^\(url=\)]` which matches any character except (, u, r, l, = and ).

Instead, you want `url=([^,]+)` which matches 'url=' then proceeds to match until it finds a  non-comma character.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks for the explanation. I just can't wrap my head around Regex

Answer (score 5):

You probably want something like the next:

```
>>> re.findall(r'url=(\w+)',st)
['these', 'are', 'test', 'questions']
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because your regex is splitting based on the letters 'url'.

This works for me:

```
re.findall(r'url=([^,]+)',st)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a regex answer, but maybe you want to take it into account:

```
In [14]: st = "url=these,url=are,url=test,url=questions"
In [15]: [item.strip(',') for item in st.split('url=') if item]
Out[15]: ['these', 'are', 'test', 'questions']
```

Comment: Actually, i have to apply this regex pattern to a large HTML file. So, i thought regex will be more faster than normal String manipulations.

Comment: Oh! speed! be careful, check it. String methods are lightning fast and often beats regex for simple searches

Comment: Nice insight, but than how should one decide

Comment: That depends on the complexity of your string vs re code. Regex allow to define very complex conditions, allowing grouping, etc. I do not use regex often (except when obliged to write or correct Perl) so I always have to check for the codes and as I'm lazy I always start with string/list methods if I can. When I write regexes and speed is a problem I always check if string methods give me better perfomance. Your mileage may vary...

Comment: So, I think a person should give String/list methods a chance before using regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall(r'url=([^,]+)', st)
```